# PHP - write to file at end of each line

Tags: php, file, append, fwrite

Assume I already have a text file which looks like:

**sample.txt**

```
This is line 1.
This is line 2.
This is line 3.
.
.
.
This is line n.
```

---

How can I append data from an array to the END of each line?

The following ONLY attaches to the line following the last line.

```
appendThese = {"append_1", "append_2", "append_3", ... , "append_n"};

foreach($appendThese as $a){

   file_put_contents('sample.txt', $a, FILE_APPEND); //Want to append each array item to the end of each line
}
```

---

Desired Result:

```
    This is line 1.append_1
    This is line 2.append_2
    This is line 3.append_3
    .
    .
    .
    This is line n.append_n
```

Comment: Read the file, append the strings and then write to file.

Comment: if it was the same string for every line you could use str_replace()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$append= array("append1","append2","append3","append4");
foreach ($lines as $key => &$value) {
    $value = $value.$append[$key];
}
file_put_contents("file.txt", implode("\n", $lines));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', file_get_contents ('sample.txt');
$contents = '';
foreach($list as $key => $item)
    $contents .= "$item.$appendThese[$key]\r\n";
file_put_contents('sample.txt', $contents);
```